How to get actual background color of TWinControl?
On a form, I have several controls placed on each other, for example:
TForm/TPageControl/TTabSheet/TGroupBox...
I'm trying to obtain the actual background color of the top-most control. How can I do this bearing in mind that each control can have different value of its ParentColor property and exact number of (nested) controls is unknown at design time?
I tried Windows API GetBkColor function, but it does not return the actual color.
I tried to write the recursive function for that but it does not work because the ParentColor property of TWinControl is protected:
  function GetColor(C: TWinControl): TColor;
  begin
    if C.ParentColor {compiling error is here} and Assigned(C.Parent) then
    begin
      Result := GetColor(C.Parent)
    end
    else
      //Result := C.Color; //compiling error is here...
      Result := C.Brush.Color;
  end;

The things probably get worse because of ParentBackround property which can have different value for each control...
So, how to get the actual background color of the top-most TWinControl?
UPDATE: It seems, just querying Brush.Color does the trick (thanks to Sherlock70). Will it always work or, maybe I need to add additional checks?

TWinControl has no exposed Color property. Look in to the Brush property, Brush.Color to be exact. https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.Brush

@Sherlock70 Good point, but... ParentColor is protected too... Updating my post.

@Sherlock70  But it seems, I do not need anything else except Brush.Color. My tests show it really works. Would you like to repost your comment as an answer?

@PetroK "the ParentColor property of TWinControl is protected" - It is actually protected in TControl, and not promoted in TWinControl. But, getting around protected is easy to work around by simply using an accessor class, eg: type TControlAccess = class(TControl) end; ... TControlAccess(C).ParentColor

@RemyLebeau Thanks. But, it seems, Brush.Color is what I needed for this task.

@PetroK Sure. But keep this technique in mind, as it can come in handy from time to time.

@RemyLebeau Agreed.

TWinControl has no exposed Color property. Look in to the Brush property, Brush.Color to be exact. For (not so much) further reading consult: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.Brush.
As to the question if this will always work...that is up to the components creator/manager. Also this might not be the right way in FMX.
